# Tomcat not able to start grails applocation

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

This is my controller:

```
 def delete(){
   def response =  fileManageService.delete(params.a,params.b,params.c)
   def SpaceVal =  fileManageService.Space(params.d)
   def message = ["message":response ,"data": SpaceVal]
   render message as JSON
 }
```

This is my service:

```
 def Space(def d){ 
    try{
        File fileObj = new File(d) 
        def useSpace = fileObj.getSpace() 
        return useSpace
    }catch(Exception e){ 
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

After adding the code to existing working application, tomcat is unable to compile the code and throws the following log error.

```
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@63e3f789')
Jul 10, 2017 11:22:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 10, 2017 11:22:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 10, 2017 11:22:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mediacast/services/FileManageService$_driveSpace_closure18
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mediacast/services/FileManageService$_driveSpace_closure18
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediacast.services.FileManageService$_driveSpace_closure18
    ... 6 more
Jul 10, 2017 11:22:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 10, 2017 11:22:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 10, 2017 11:22:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mediacast/services/FileManageService$_Space_closure18
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mediacast/services/FileManageService$_Space_closure18
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediacast.services.FileManageService$_Space_closure18
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in your logs, but they all come down to the fact that FileManageService is not present.  You did not provide the whole service here (nor do you really need to) but my guess is that there is a compilation error somewhere in that file, and it is not successfully compiling.  Consequently, it is not included in your application and is not present when you call it.

Use your IDE (if you have one, and if you don't, there are good free ones available!  Look at Intellij!) to track down the error in your code.

Comment: Also, per convention, don't name methods with a first capital letter.  That makes it look like an inner class and really makes debugging harder!

Comment: the application worked perfectly before adding the code snippet and when I removed service method and deploy,again it compiled successfully.

Comment: What is your File object?  I don't see a getSpace() method on java.io.File, or the Groovy enhancements to it.